# How to create a list of different data types, iterate and perform different actions based on type?

Tags: java

I have a list of vars made up of strings, doubles and ints which I want to store in one list, iterate through the list and perform different actions based on the type of data it is.

Initially I thought I could create an ArrayList to achieve this, but some of these are primitive types and not objects, so this did not work.

I do not know how many of each item the list will have, so I do not think I can create an object to hold all the different types for this.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?  Maybe there is a better way to achieve that.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that wrapper classes exist for each primitive type? See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class). Also, [autoboxin/unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) eases this even more.

Comment: You'll find that your ArrayList already contains wrappers for the primitive types that you added to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Class is also alternative way to achieve this as we can store any type. In 
    Following solution I have created Employee class with different type of 
   variable.

   ```
       public class Employee {

      static List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
       private int id;
       private String firstName;
       private int age;
       private double salary;
       private String department;

       public Employee(int id, String firstName, int age, double salary, 
       String department) {
       this.id = id;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.age = age;
       this.salary = salary;
       this.department = department;
       }

       public static void main(String[] argv) {
       Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, "Pavan", 45, 20000.00, 
       "Uppal");
       Employee employee2 = new Employee(2, "Mahesh", 35, 10000.00, 
       "Uppal");       

       employeeList.add(employee1);
       employeeList.add(employee2);

      }

    }
   ```

   2.Other alternative is  Create Arraylist of object type

   ```
    List<Object> list=new Arraylist<Object>();
    list.add(100);
    list.add("hi")
    list.add(12.0)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Object representation from a primitive type like Float instead of float, Integer instead of integer, etc. This way you can identify cases where data is not valid using the null concept instead of a default value as will happens with the primitive types.
If you want an special behavior, you can implement some patter like the Visitor Pattern (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm).